# Split Ajax Resuls by Comma Into UL List

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML list coming back via ajax. However all the entries are split by a comma. How would I split each result by a comma and have it append to /li in order?

*HTML*

```
   <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input
              class="form-control mr-sm-2"
              type="text"
              name="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
  </form>

 <ul id="response">
          <li>Attack
          </li>
          <li>Defence
          </li>
          <li>Strength
          </li>
          <li>HitPoints
          </li>
 </ul>
```

*Jquery*

```
$('#search-btn').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
var url = "?=";
var searchValue = $('input[name="search"]').val();
var urlAddition = url + searchValue 
$.ajax({
  url: urlAddition,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
     $('ul#response').html(data);
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string by comma and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through the items, create li and append them to ul.

```js
const res = 'Attack, Defence, Strength, HitPoints';

const list = res.split(",");

$('#response').html(list.map(item => '<li>' + item + '</li>').join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="response"></ul>
```